# Choosing a calendar date

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I wanted to choose the month in the calendar, for example if I give "May" then it should select the may moth calendar, I have tried with then below while loop, however it is not identifying the month based on the text I provided, instead it is keep on clicking the next button, could someone help please.

here is my source code,

Here is my code,

```
while(!remoteDriver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@role='heading']/strong")).getText().contains("April 2018"))
{
    remoteDriver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='refine-results']/cc-filters/div[1]/ul/li[3]/cc-date-picker/div/div/div[2]/span/div/ul/li/div/div/div/table/thead/tr[1]/th[3]/button/i")).click();
}
```

Here is the source code:

```
<button id="datepicker-2263-7581-title" role="heading" aria-live="assertive" aria-atomic="true" type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm uib-title" ng-click="toggleMode()" ng-disabled="datepickerMode === maxMode" tabindex="-1"><strong class="ng-binding">April 2018</strong></button>
```

Comment: I cannot see your source code

Comment: Please provide relevant _HTML_